# вычисление с заданной точностью:цикл не завершается

Tags: c

Есть ряд:
[image]
Необходимо написать программу с вычислением с заданной точностью. Проблема в том, что цикл не завершается, пока переменная `result` не достигнет `total'a`

Сам код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double summ(int);
double summ(int N)
{
    int i;
    double res1=1, res2=0;
    for(i=1;i<=N;i+=2)
    {
        res1 = 1.0/i * res1;
        res2 += res1;
    }
    return res2;
}

double dell(int);
double dell(int N)
{
    double a=1.0;
    a=N/a+1;
    N-=1;
    while (N>=1)
    {
        a=N/a+1;
        N-=1;
    }
    a=1.0/a;
    return a;
}




int main()
{
    double e = exp(1.0), p = acos(-1.0), result=0, accuracy,total;
    int N=1;
    printf("input accuracy = "); scanf("%f", &accuracy);
    total = sqrt((e * p)/2.0);
    do
    {
        result = summ(N) + dell(N);
        N+=1;
    }
    while (fabs(total - result) > accuracy);
    printf("total  = %f\nresult = %f\niterations = %d",total, result, N);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не вдаваясь во все, сразу бросилось в глаза - `scanf("%f", &accuracy);` - но `%f` - это для `float`, не для `double`. Проверьте, чему *реально* оказывается равна `accuracy` после ввода...

Comment: Вы правы, в этом и заключалась ошибка, спасибо.